# Contradicting results in FORTRAN 77

Tags: loops, fortran, iteration, fortran77

I have written a simple FORTRAN 77 [code](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6vh5oi2hwqynyia/Neta_p6.for) for numerically solving an equation using a specific iterative scheme (Neta's sixth order).

Then I made a simple change. In particular, I transferred the entire iterative scheme from inside the main loop into an external subroutine. However the results of the new [revised code](http://www.mediafire.com/file/brc8rwsipwp3h56/Neta2_p6.for) do not match with the previous ones.

Any ideas why? I suppose there must be a simple trivial mistake which however I cannot see! Needless to say, that any comments for making the codes more efficient or faster are more than welcome.

Many thanks in advance.

**ORIGINAL CODE**

```
  PROGRAM NETA_P6

  DOUBLE PRECISION tol,acc,Re0,Im0,Re,Im,Ref,Imf
  DOUBLE PRECISION b,d1,d2
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z0,z1,zf,dz,F,DF
  DOUBLE COMPLEX un,yn,zn
  INTEGER iter,iterf,max_iter

  DOUBLE PRECISION a,Q
  COMMON /param/a,Q

  Re0=-5d0
  Im0=-5d0

  a=0d0
  Q=0d0
  tol=1d-15
  acc=1d-10
  max_iter=500

  z0=DCMPLX(Re0,Im0)
  iter=0

  DO
    un=F(z0)/DF(z0)
    b=-0.5d0
    yn=z0-un
    zn=yn-F(yn)/DF(z0)*(F(z0)+b*F(yn))/(F(z0)+(b-2d0)*F(yn))
    d1=ABS(yn)
    d2=ABS(yn-zn)
    IF(d1.LT.tol)THEN
      z1=z0
    ELSEIF(d2.LT.tol)THEN
      z1=yn  
    ELSE  
      z1=zn-F(zn)/DF(z0)*(F(z0)-F(yn))/(F(z0)-3d0*F(yn)) 
    ENDIF
    dz=z1-z0
    Re=DABS(DBLE(dz))
    Im=DABS(DIMAG(dz))
    iter=iter+1
    WRITE(*,10)iter,dz,z1
    IF((Re.LT.tol.AND.Im.LT.tol).OR.iter.GE.max_iter)GOTO 7
    z0=z1
  END DO

  7    CONTINUE

  zf=z1
  Ref=DBLE(zf)
  Imf=DIMAG(zf)
  iterf=iter

 c     ELIMINATING VERY SMALL NUMBERS < 1d-15 

  IF(DABS(Ref).LT.acc)Ref=0d0
  IF(DABS(Imf).LT.acc)Imf=0d0

  WRITE(*,*)
  WRITE(*,*)'------------------------------------------'      
  IF(iter.LT.max_iter)THEN
    WRITE(*,*)'FOR THE INITIAL POINT WITH:'
    WRITE(*,11)Re0
    WRITE(*,12)Im0
    WRITE(*,*)'THE METHOD CONVERGED TO: '
    WRITE(*,13)Ref
    WRITE(*,14)Imf
    WRITE(*,15)iter
  ELSEIF(iter.GE.max_iter)THEN
    WRITE(*,*)'FOR THE INITIAL POINT WITH:'
    WRITE(*,11)Re0
    WRITE(*,12)Im0
    WRITE(*,*)'THE METHOD DID NOT CONVERGE' 
    WRITE(*,15)iter
  ENDIF
  WRITE(*,*)'------------------------------------------'

c     FORMATS
10   FORMAT(2x,'i = ',i3,/2x,'dz  = ',2(2x,E22.16),/2x,
 & 'z_0 = ',2(2x,E22.16))
11   FORMAT(1x,'Re[z0]  = ',F22.16)   
12   FORMAT(1x,'Im[z0]  = ',F22.16)
13   FORMAt(1x,'Re[zf]  = ',E22.16)
14   FORMAT(1x,'Im[zf]  = ',E22.16)
15   FORMAT(1x,'AFTER N = ',i3,' ITERATIONS')

  PAUSE

  END
```

---

```
  DOUBLE COMPLEX FUNCTION F(z)  ! main function
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z

  DOUBLE PRECISION a,Q
  COMMON /param/a,Q

  F=3d0*z-z/(SQRT(z**2))**3*(1d0+3d0*a/2d0/(SQRT(z**2))**2)-Q

  RETURN
  END
```

---

```
  DOUBLE COMPLEX FUNCTION DF(z)  ! first order derivative
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z

  DOUBLE PRECISION a,Q
  COMMON /param/a,Q

  DF=(3d0*z**6+2d0*SQRT(z**2)*(3d0*a+z**2))/z**6

  RETURN
  END
```

---

**REVISED CODE**

```
  PROGRAM NETA2_P6

  DOUBLE PRECISION tol,acc,Re0,Im0,Re,Im,Ref,Imf
  DOUBLE PRECISION b,d1,d2
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z0,z1,zf,dz,F,DF
  DOUBLE COMPLEX un,yn,zn,inz,outz
  INTEGER iter,iterf,max_iter

  DOUBLE PRECISION a,Q
  COMMON /param/a,Q

  Re0=-5d0
  Im0=-5d0

  a=0d0
  Q=0d0
  tol=1d-15
  acc=1d-10
  max_iter=500

  z0=DCMPLX(Re0,Im0)
  iter=0

  DO
    inz=z0
    CALL N6(inz,outz)  
    z1=outz
    dz=z1-z0
    Re=DABS(DBLE(dz))
    Im=DABS(DIMAG(dz))
    iter=iter+1
    WRITE(*,10)iter,dz,z1
    IF((Re.LT.tol.AND.Im.LT.tol).OR.iter.GE.max_iter)GOTO 7
    z0=z1
  END DO

   7    CONTINUE

  zf=z1
  Ref=DBLE(zf)
  Imf=DIMAG(zf)
  iterf=iter

 c     ELIMINATING VERY SMALL NUMBERS < 1d-15 

  IF(DABS(Ref).LT.acc)Ref=0d0
  IF(DABS(Imf).LT.acc)Imf=0d0

  WRITE(*,*)
  WRITE(*,*)'------------------------------------------'      
  IF(iter.LT.max_iter)THEN
    WRITE(*,*)'FOR THE INITIAL POINT WITH:'
    WRITE(*,11)Re0
    WRITE(*,12)Im0
    WRITE(*,*)'THE METHOD CONVERGED TO: '
    WRITE(*,13)Ref
    WRITE(*,14)Imf
    WRITE(*,15)iter
  ELSEIF(iter.GE.max_iter)THEN
    WRITE(*,*)'FOR THE INITIAL POINT WITH:'
    WRITE(*,11)Re0
    WRITE(*,12)Im0
    WRITE(*,*)'THE METHOD DID NOT CONVERGE' 
    WRITE(*,15)iter
  ENDIF
  WRITE(*,*)'------------------------------------------'

 c     FORMATS
 10   FORMAT(2x,'i = ',i3,/2x,'dz  = ',2(2x,E22.16),/2x,
 & 'z_0 = ',2(2x,E22.16))
 11   FORMAT(1x,'Re[z0]  = ',F22.16)   
 12   FORMAT(1x,'Im[z0]  = ',F22.16)
 13   FORMAt(1x,'Re[zf]  = ',E22.16)
 14   FORMAT(1x,'Im[zf]  = ',E22.16)
 15   FORMAT(1x,'AFTER N = ',i3,' ITERATIONS')

  PAUSE

  END
```

---

```
  DOUBLE COMPLEX FUNCTION F(z)  ! main function
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z

  DOUBLE PRECISION a,Q
  COMMON /param/a,Q

  F=3d0*z-z/(SQRT(z**2))**3*(1d0+3d0*a/2d0/(SQRT(z**2))**2)-Q

  RETURN
  END
```

---

```
  DOUBLE COMPLEX FUNCTION DF(z)  ! first order derivative
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z

  DOUBLE PRECISION a,Q
  COMMON /param/a,Q

  DF=(3d0*z**6+2d0*SQRT(z**2)*(3d0*a+z**2))/z**6

  RETURN
  END
```

---

```
  SUBROUTINE N6(z0,z1)

  DOUBLE PRECISION b,d1,d2,tol      
  DOUBLE COMPLEX z0,z1,F,DF
  DOUBLE COMPLEX un,yn,zn

  tol=1d-15
  un=F(z0)/DF(z0)
  b=-0.5d0
  yn=z0-un
  zn=yn-F(yn)/DF(z0)*(F(z0)+b*F(yn))/(F(z0)+(b-2d0)*F(yn))
  d1=ABS(yn)
  d2=ABS(yn-zn)
  IF(d1.LT.tol)THEN
    z1=z0
  ELSEIF(d2.LT.tol)THEN
    z1=yn  
  ELSE  
    z1=zn-F(zn)/DF(z0)*(F(z0)-F(yn))/(F(z0)-3d0*F(yn)) 
  ENDIF

  RETURN
  END
```

---

Comment: Please read the instructions at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @francescalus I edited my question by adding the codes.

Comment: @ja72 Thanks for the suggestion. Please see my edit.

Comment: Is this really the _minimal_ code needed to reproduce the problem? And can please elaborate on how the results are wrong. What values you expect and what do you get?

Comment: You really need to explain the output and why are those values you get wrong. Also try to make the codes shorter. Delete parts not relevant to this question or at least explain where the codes differ.

Comment: If you add `IMPLICIT NONE` to the original and modified code, does the problem persist? (Note: this will likely involve modifying both original and revised code) Also, does the subroutine expect that local variables are persistent? The main point is that you have moved code from one 'scope' to another so it's likely some variables you expect to be set or retain a persistent value are not being handled as expected within the scope of the new routine.

Comment: Also, (though not related to the question), `SQRT(z**2)` might not be what you expect (I guess you mean abs(z)?), so in that case please be careful... (sqrt(z**2) is equal to z when Re{z} > 0, while -z when Re{z} < 0).